# Tamil Fonts other than wntml10, 12, 17

Tags: fonts, indic

Can we use Tamil Fonts other than `wntml10`, `12` and `17` when we use itrans53.2 in Latex?

Comment: What is `itrans53.2` ?

Comment: There are `itrans` compatible mappings for XeTeX. Maybe you could switch to XeLaTeX.

Comment: itrans is a package available in CTAN. Enable us to produce pdf files with two files <filename-pre.tex> and <filename.tex>. Itrans.exe converts <filename-pre.tex> into <filename.tex>. When we build and view <filename.tex> we will get pdf doc in Tamil. Unicode conversion.

Comment: This is not with `itrans`, but you can use any OpenType font that supports Tamil [with XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43676/how-to-typeset-document-in-indian-script).