# Writing in தமிழ் (Tamil)

Tags: fonts, fontspec, tamil

I see from [this answer in tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43676/how-to-typeset-document-in-indian-script/43690#43690) that to write in Tamil I need to use `XeLaTeX` to compile the document.

But my case is a bit different. I am writing my thesis and my references
come from `BibTeX`. At the moment I am using `TexMaker` to compile my document
via

```
PdfLaTeX + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTex(x2) + View Pdf
```

I see that there exists an option for XeLaTex, but this is without 
`Bib(la)tex` for my reference.

**I just need to write one sentence in Tamil in the entire document**, is there an easy solution to this?

Comment: Depends a bit on the length of the sentence. I would probably create a graphic and include it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: That is exactly what I was thinking about! But I also need to add words in English in between the sentence. Can you provide a minimal example so that the graphic looks as though it has been typed?

Comment: Is there a reason why could not use XeLaTeX instead?

Comment: Oh, never mind, you only need one sentence...

Comment: @ThePredator Check the anwer here  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319/latex-xetex-setup-tamil-indic-languages
It might help.

Comment: @Tanvir: The answer to that question requires the use of compiling with XeLaTeX and I don't have a option in TeXMakeR to compile XeLaTeX with BibTeX

Comment: Please scroll down to the third answer in that link.the answer by LianTze.. ... it asks you to install itrans and itrans-fonts., for which PdfLatex works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following Ulrike's suggestion, and my code at [create latex symbol from vector graphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224357/create-latex-symbol-from-vector-graphics/224359#224359).  To get `phrase1.jpg`, I just cropped the title to this page.  To get `phrase2.jpg`, I cropped `phrase1`, so as to demonstrate the method when the descenders are different for each phrase (only change is the `\raisebox` argument).

The `scalerel` approach adopted will scale the graphics to the height of a letter `X`, regardless of the current font size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\fboxsep=-\fboxrule
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\phraseA{\scalerel*{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\raisebox{-9pt}{\includegraphics{phrase1}}}\dp0=0pt\box0}{X}}
\def\phraseB{\scalerel*{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\raisebox{-2pt}{\includegraphics{phrase2}}}\dp0=0pt\box0}{X}}
\begin{document}
Can I insert my \phraseA{} inline along with \phraseB?

\tiny Can I insert my \phraseA{} inline along with \phraseB?

The original images:\fboxsep=1pt\relax
\fbox{\includegraphics{phrase1}} and \fbox{\includegraphics{phrase2}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If, instead of cropping jpgs with different top/bottom cut lines, you use Xelatex to to create a `standalone` PDF of `\strut<Tamil word or phrase>` with minimal margin, then each implementation of of `\phraseX` will use the identical `\raisebox` parameters.  Furthermore, the image, deriving from a vector graphic PDF, should scale without pixelation.

Comment: possibly just need `\includegraphics[height=1ex]{phrase2}` using a non-dependent length and skipping the measuring.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Maybe so...but in that case, `\includegraphics` is doing the measuring and scaling, rather than `scalerel`.  There is still the issue of descenders.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\phraseB{}` ??

Comment: @ThePredator One only need follow it with a `{}` if a space needs to be preserved afterwards.  In this case, since a `?` immediately follows, the `{}` can be dispensed with.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Thank you very much! One final question, if I need to increase the font of a word, i.e. the graphic, what should I do? It now fit's, but is really tiny compared to the other words in the sentence

Comment: @ThePredator Two choices: 1) crop the images tighter so there is no white zone above the top/below the bottom of the text images; or 2) Instead of using `{X}` as the second argument of the `scalerel*` macro, use something taller, such as `{\rule{0pt}{\ht\strutbox}}`.  If you go taller than `\ht\strutbox`, it will affect the line spacing unless you `\smash` the result.